# MySQL SELECT query -> UPDATE (numbering grouped by rows)

Tags: mysql

This query selects the desired result as it should: it puts row numbers for each id, grouped by id, starting from 1 again at the each id:

```
SELECT `id_product`,
       `lowest_price`,
       IF(@CG=`id_product`, @I:=@I+1, @I:=1) AS rownr,
       @CG:=`id_product` AS run_order
FROM  `table`
INNER JOIN (SELECT @I:=0, @CG:=-1) x
ORDER BY id_product ASC, lowest_price ASC
```

I am having trouble updating the table:
UPDATE `table` SET row_number = .....

Solved it with temporary table, but is there any more neat solution?